# "Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'" despite having allowed DNS via ufw

Tags: debian, dns, firewall, ufw

So I denied everything except DNS, HTTPS and HTTP in the gufw firewall. `ufw status verbose` looks good with no DENY for port 53 and only allows at the bottom of it. I even executed `sudo ufw allow 53/udp` and also tried setting the DNS nameserver to 8.8.8.8. Still it doesn't work: apt-get update gives me "Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'". Pings don't work either.

In /var/log/syslog it also says:

> WARNING: Can't read main.cvd header from db.local.clamav.net (IP: )
>   WARNING: Can't query current.cvd.clamav.net
>   WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
>   Reading CVD header (main.cvd): ERROR: Can't get information about database.clamav.net: Temporary failure in name resolution.

and

> Activating service name='org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper' (using servicehelper)

avahi-daemon is set to DENY in case that matters.
Also a ClamAV scan found the same as listed in [my question here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166385/clamav-findings-under-debian-9-libreofficemacros-and-pua-win-exploit-cve-2012-0)

It worked earlier using iptables which basically had the same rules for DNS.

I'm running a freshly installed Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Any ideas what might be causing this? How can I get it working?

Comment: DNS uses 53/tCP too

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Had that allowed too. I now explicitly allowed it via `ufw allow 53/tcp` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: use `dig` to troubleshoot and then see with tcpdump/wireshark if packets are sent correctly first